# Rendering PDF from Markdown file with literal emoji characters using Pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'd like to convert markdown text like:

```
This is a smile
```

To a PDF with the emoji on it. To be clear, I want to be able to insert the emoji character itself in the source text, not something like `:smile:`.

How can I do this with Pandoc?

Answer (score 5):

After initially having read the OP too superficially (overlooking his need to ***NOT*** use *`:smile:`* & friends in his source Markdown), here is a better answer. Try one of these:

```
pandoc my.markdown -o emoji.pdf --pdf-engine=lualatex -V mainfont="DejaVu Sans"
pandoc my.markdown -o emoji.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex  -V mainfont="DejaVu Sans"
```

If you use the default pdf-engine (*`pdflatex`*), you'll not succeed, but get an error like

```
 ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+1F600)
 (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

If you do not specify the <strike>*`mainfonts`*</strike> *`mainfont`* param, you'll get an warning message of

```
 [WARNING] Missing character: There is no  (U+1F604) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;
```

for XeLaTeX and of

```
 [WARNING] Missing character: There is no  in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

---

### Update

Thanks to @jpnadas for noticing a typo in my answer. The parameter should be `-V mainfont=...` (not `-V mainfonts`!).

I leave it to the reader(s) to test the correct commands and look at their results:

```
pandoc -o emoji.pdf --pdf-engine=lualatex -V mainfont="DejaVu Sans"
pandoc -o emoji.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex  -V mainfont="DejaVu Sans"
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in your answer, shouldn't the parameter be `mainfont`, as in `-V mainfont="DejaVu Sans"`?

Comment: @jpnadas: You are right. Thanks for noticing. I'll fix it.

Comment: Is there another font I could try? I'm using MacTex 2019 Distribution on a Mac. I just get an error with xelatex: "kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `DejaVu Sans', contains ' '" and "! Package fontspec Error: The font "DejaVu Sans" cannot be found."   With lualatex I'm getting the warning message you list above: "[WARNING] Missing character: There is no  (U+1F316) (U+1F316) in font DejaVuSans:mode=node;scrip". I see that the space was removed. Not sure what did that. I specified the font as "DejaVu Sans"

Comment: 2022, pandoc respond with `! Package fontspec Error: The font "DejaVu Sans" cannot be found.`. Any idea's to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `:smile:` with HTML like so:

```
This is a smile <img src="https://github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f604.png"/>
```

Comment: Thing is I have sources with literal emoji already and I'm specifically trying to not have to replace them with anything, but have the unicode characters be properly rendered directly.